# "The server machine is shutting down. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704E7)" while accessing Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I have this fragment of code:

```
Uri uri;
try {
    uri = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUri;
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    // exception is thrown
}
```

I get the exception:

> ex = {System.Exception: The server machine is shutting down.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704E7)    at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.get_LinkUri()    at
>   MyApp.Controls.Screens.MainScreenControl..ctor()}

What does it mean and how can I avoid this exception?

The similar, unresolved question is here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6ebd1b23-b37b-4cc5-a840-d966527f7199/the-server-machine-is-shutting-down-exception-from-hresult-0x800704e7?forum=wpsubmit .

Comment: Is the server machine actually shutting down? Find out why it is shutting down - a likely candidate is that windows updates are being applied, in which case you need to disable the update service and only run it when you want it to run. There's not much to go on here.

Comment: @user1666620 "Is the server machine actually shutting down?" I don't even know where should I look for this server and where this server is. I just try to read the standard property `LinkUri`  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUri);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-WindowsPhoneApp,Version%3Dv8.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Can you post what the actual Uri is? Or does it not even get that far?

Comment: @Hank The exception is thrown on `uri = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUri;`, so `uri` is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a temporary Windows Store server problem.